# Why didn't Tobey tell the police that Julia could confirm Dino was with them before the illegal race?

Tags: plot-explanation, need-for-speed

During the interrogation in *Need for Speed*, the police state that Dino has two witnesses to verify he wasn't at the race (the one where Pete died), he was someplace else, but Julia **and** the buyer saw Dino at the track, both could confirm it, and had no reason to lie.

Why didn't Tobey tell the police to ask Julia or the buyer to confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Since the race was on public roads and not at the track, it doesn't matter if Julia and the buyer say they saw Dino at the track - they can't say for sure that he WAS at the race, and Dino had witnesses to say he wasn't.

The most they could definitively say is that Dino agreed to race.  And even if they did say as much to the police, Dino just has to say "I didn't show up, here are my witnesses to prove it" and unless the police have enough information to go digging into those false alibis (presumably they had no reason to distrust the witnesses) this would be accepted, and Dino cleared of any involvement.  Tobey was absolutely there and not denying the fact, plus he was distraught over the death of Pete so probably in shock at the time.

I always thought the fact that the Koenigsegg Ageras belonged to Dino's uncle (? I'm going from memory here, might have been some other relative) should have made the police look more closely at him, but clearly they didn't.

Comment: I like this answer, but a few corrections, Julia is the British girl who is a buyer for someone else, Pete's sister was Anita. My whole point was if Julia, the buyer and Tobey all claim that Dino agreed to race, won't it be enough to at least check it out? Determine if there was any damage to Dino's car and if so, question him. It was Dino's uncle who owned the cars (which were illegally imported).

Comment: Another thing too, the final race at the end, where Tobey stops to help Dino, the announcer and guy running the race says the license plate matches the car that killed Pete, if they had the plates and with Tobey's claim that Dino did race, wouldn't that be enough for a questioning?

Comment: Yes, but Dino hid that car from the police - it was tucked away in a workshop somewhere.  Anita (got my names mixed up) located it eventually by looking through the invoices on Dino's PC.

Answer (score 0):

They did not start the race from the track where they were showing the "Super Mustang" to Julia and her client. If you remember they went to Dino's house to get the Koenigsegg Agera R's from his own garage so there was no one other then the people that must work for Dino (maids, butler, etc.)